# Does electric charge affect gas volume?

Tags: charge, gas

The gas is contained within an elastic balloon of some sort. The balloon itself is in a vacuum.

I assume that adding charge to a gas would increase its volume because of atoms with same charge pushing against each other. Would adding charge to a gas really change its volume?

Comment: Where you you hold your gas that it can freely change its volume? In a lab container, you might rather expect increased pressure (convert charge density into energy density - which is exactly the same as pressure). Then again, the repelling charges would quickly reach the container walls ... I suppose

Comment: Edited. Still, pressure and volume are closely related, so it shouldnt really matter? And even if charges reached container walls, if walls themselves don't conduct charge to anywhere else, then charge should be distributed in both walls and gas?